# ROS Answers SE migration: Pick function

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Please let me know, what is the disfference between:

1. pick() function
2. And simple scenario in which i use attach and detach object after reaching to the defined pick and place positions respectively.

How pick is different from simple attach and also Please let me know what would be the most likely (grasp/grasps) in the pick function?  where should i get the detailed information about the arguments of pick function?
Thanks!
-I am working on ABB IRB4600 robot / ROS indigo and  intend to perfom simple pick and place task using moveit!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260866/pick-function/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you have a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/244831/moveit-pick-too-complicated/ ?

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0